# Загрузка фото input type="file"

Tags: php, html, файлы, input

Есть форма Html:

```
<form method="post" action=""/>
    <input  required="required" name="image" type="file"   />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

`php` код:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
    $uploaddir = '../images/articles/';       
    $prev = $uploaddir.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
     copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $prev);
}
```

Он видит `$_POST['image']`, но не видит `$_FILES['image']`, в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте к form: enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы хотите изобрести велосипед, который уже давно изобрели. Сейчас в интернете можно найти сотни, уже готовых форм загрузки картинок на сайт, от простых до загрузки через Ajax с индикатором загрузки. Для того чтобы сделать хорошую форму загрузки фото нужно, сделать несколько проверок например расширение файла, размер файла и так далее.

Html:

```
<form action="./upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p><input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Загрузить фаил"></p>
</form>
```

Php:

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // Допустимые типы файлов
$max_filesize = 524288; // Максимальный размер файла в байтах (в данном случае он равен 0.5 Мб).
$upload_path = './files/'; // Папка, куда будут загружаться файлы .
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name']; // В переменную $filename заносим имя файла (включая расширение).
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // В переменную $ext заносим расширение загруженного файла.

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes)) // Сверяем полученное расширение со списком допутимых расширений. 
die('Данный тип файла не поддерживается.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize) // Проверим размер загруженного файла.
die('Фаил слишком большой.');

if(!is_writable($upload_path)) // Проверяем, доступна ли на запись папка.
die('Невозможно загрузить фаил в папку. Установите права доступа - 777.');

// Загружаем фаил в указанную папку.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
{
    echo 'Ваш фаил успешно загружен ';
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '<img src="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" width="300" >';
} else {
    echo 'При загрузке возникли ошибки. Попробуйте ещё раз.';
}
```